# PhoneGap - Max Number of Active Media Objects Allowed?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, media

I am using PhoneGap (Cordova) on Android and am playing multiple media objects at the same time. I am aware that there is a max number of concurrent media objects permitted due to resource restrictions. I can confirm this by the app crashing when I have too many at once.

I have searched but can not find out what is the limit on the number of active media objects at the same time? Once I know what the upper cap is I can restrict the number of sounds to just under that so it doesn't crash.

Does anyone know the max number of active media objects allowed within Phonegap for Android? Or is it simply relative to the device you are using?

I am using .release() after each play of a sound but my worry is concurrent sounds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to write a manager to limit the number of concurrent sounds.

I can't answer to the limit, but I suspect it would vary dependent on the capabilities of the device anyway.

Comment: yes the manager would be simple to write, but without knowing the upper limit it can't be completed properly

Comment: You can't be certain, but you can make a reasonable assumption, an implement that limit yourself.  Unless you are writing a 64 track audio mixer for use on Android, in which case, good luck! :)